# Как защитить api ключ yandex maps api

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Скажите, как защитить API ключ карт?
Правильно я понимаю, что ключ лежит в открытом виде моего сайта.
И его можно найти/просмотреть по исходным кодам сайта.
Я использую Angular 6.
То есть любой может скопировать мой платный ключ и использовать его.
Как этого избежать, или я что то не так понимаю?

Comment: Насколько я знаю ключ привязан к домену

Comment: с этим вопросом лучше сразу в техподдержку Яндекса.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответ от тех. поддержки: "Ключ  — это, в первую очередь, идентификатор проекта. При получении ключа, Вы можете указать адрес сайта, где он будет использоваться."